# What happens when I call a function before returning the current function

Tags: objective-c, function, scope, heap-memory, stack-memory

This is a general programming question. I am using Objective-C but could be done in any other language.

I am having the following function:

```
-(BOOL)shouldMoveToColumn:(NSInteger)column_ andRow:(NSInteger)row_ {

    if (![super shouldMoveToColumn:column_ andRow:row_]) {

        state_ = kSBEEnemyState_Moving;

        [self prepareForMoving];
        [self handle];

        return NO;
    }

    // otherwise ...
    // some other calculations ....
    return YES;
}
```

Calling `[self handle]` before returning a NO however leads to perform an operation that will again call `-(BOOL)shouldMoveToColumn:column_ andRow:row_`.

I was asking myself if this would mean that when calling `[self handle]` before returning the function the function will probably never be closed and thus leading to a "stack overflow" since we keep on moving on the heap without ever closing and moving back.

So I thought if it would be better to call `[self handle]` on a different thread to make sure the function will return and close the function!?

I am not really sure if this is the right behavior but from my understanding about functions, heap, stack and returning that's what happens.

EDIT:

I just read about recursive calls on the internet and stumbled over a Wikipedia article called "Infinite Recursion". The description to it can be seen as an important part of an answer to my question:

> **Infinite recursion**
>
> The most common cause of stack overflow is excessively deep or infinite
>   recursion, in which a function calls itself so many times that the
>   space needed to store the variables and information associated with
>   each call is more than can fit on the stack.
>
> Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#Very_deep_recursion

That's exactly what I was expecting to happen. And although this never happened when running my code so far - even for a very long time. I am however pretty sure that it is best to call `[self handle]` on a different thread.

Comment: I don't clearly understand your code, but in the case of recursive calls, you should be clear that the recursion will stop at some condition. ie-the if case will fail at some time.

Comment: It looks to me like this will lead to a recursive loop, and calling on a different thread is no solution.  The code is basically broken.